# DHCP packets cut off after configuring VLANs on switch

Tags: networking, dhcp, switch, dhcp-server

I initially set up my switch taking inputs from my router, modem, and all network devices... and quickly found that was a bad idea when I tested DHCP results and found I was getting responses from the web. So I decided to use VLANs to limit access to the modem's port on the switch to the router's WAN port on the switch. After a bit of trial and error I've found a solution that works, with one caveat... wired connections in VLAN 20 (below) are not receiving DHCP responses. I've verified this with a "DHCP Checker" tool that shows no DHCP packets being received on the host. I can set the host to use a static IP and then they connect fine -- but I want the DHCP functionality.

However, wireless hosts connecting to the router receive DHCP responses just fine.

I'm adding a picture of my VLAN/switch diagram. Does anyone know why this setup could result in DHCP packets dying when routing through the switch?

[image: Network VLAN Diagram]

[image: PVID Configuration]

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the switch configuration. Switches operate at layer 2, so they can't tell a DHCP packet from anything else.   I would look more at the router.

Comment: Ok, weird. Either something needed time to reset last night (when I was changing configs back and forth like a madman)... or adding the definition of the default gateway on the host fixed things. The switch has that defined though so I'm guessing it was just a ghost last night. Everything working fine now, thank you for your eyes Ron!

Comment: @RonTrunk how should I close this out?